# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to move the my sql working to PDO but it showing the following
 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/content/58/9508458/html/pa/test. php on line 12

orginal code

```
<?php
$pdfreq=$_GET['dadi'];
include('config.php');
require('fpdf.php');
$link =mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);



$update = "UPDATE mastertable SET pdfstatus =1 WHERE id_pk = $pdfreq";
mysql_query($update, $link);
```

Replaced with

```
<?php
$pdfreq=$_GET['dadi'];
include('config.php');
require('fpdf.php');
$link =mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);



$sql = "UPDATE mastertable SET pdfstatus=?, WHERE id_pk=?";
$q = $link->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(1,$pdfreq));
```

Comment: You are attempting to mix PDO with the old `mysql_*()` functions, which is not possible. PDO is a separate API, with a different connect method.

Comment: @sixeightzero: I think that's what one would call a minor edit!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$link` variable is not a PDO object.  You should replace:

```
$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

With:

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host",$username,$password);
```

Comment: But pdfstatus is not setting to 1

Comment: @Tom: Try adding `$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);` before your call to `$q->execute();`.  It will probably point out that you have a syntax error in your query owing to the comma between the first `?` and `WHERE`.

Comment: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in /home/content/58/9508458/html/pa/test. php on line 12

Comment: @Tom: That should have been added in conjunction with the change given in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You are using MySQL helper functions, not PDO or MySQLi.

**Prepare will not work with what you are doing**

You need to change your syntax to, note the trailing `i` in MySQLi

```
<?php
$pdfreq=$_GET['dadi'];
$id = 1;
include('config.php');
require('fpdf.php');
$link = new mysqli($db_host,$username,$password, $db_name);

$sql = "UPDATE mastertable SET pdfstatus=? WHERE id_pk=?";
$q = $link->prepare($sql);

$q->bind_param("is", $id, $pdfreq);
$q->execute();
```

Since MySQL does not have a prepare method, your value will never get set to 1, and you will fail with `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`

If you wish to use [PDO see the PDO Documentation on PHP.Net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: two errors now Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/content/58/9508458/html/pabrowser/ccc.php on line 10

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/content/58/9508458/html/pabrowser/ccc.php on line 14

Comment: Given that the OP specifically says "*I am trying to move the my sql working to PDO*", I don't see how suggesting MySQLi helps (except for your final sentence linking to the PDO section of the manual).

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/content/58/9508458/html/pabrowser/ccc.php on line 13

Comment: From the looks of the OP's code above, I don't think they know the difference between PDO and MySQLi. They tried to adapt their code to syntax closer to MySQLi, hence the suggestion.

Comment: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/content/58/9508458/html/pabrowser/ccc.php on line 14

Comment: I think it was failing because there was an extra `,` in your original query before `WHERE`, removed it try again.

Comment: i removed  , but Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /home/content/58/9508458/html/pabrowser/ccc.php on line 14

Comment: That had to do with passing the 1 in the bind_param statement. Had to be defined as a $var first.